# How to delete angularfire object after calling $bindTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How do you delete an object from firebase after calling angularfire's `$bindTo()` on the object. For some reason calling `$bindTo()` seems to remove the `$remove()` function from the object.

For example the delete button in the following app doesn't work unless you comment out the `$bindTo` line.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/robianmcd/pen/WvbBpg?editors=101)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);

app.controller('myCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var self = this;
  this.test = $firebaseObject(new Firebase('https://bindtoissue.firebaseio-demo.com/test'));

  //if you comment out this line then the delete button will work.
  this.test.$bindTo($scope, 'ctrl.test');

  this.test.$loaded(function() {
    self.test.one = 1;
    self.test.two = 2;
    self.test.three = 3;
  });
}

MyCtrl.prototype.delete = function() {
  //$remove is undefined
  this.test.$remove();
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.delete()">delete</button>
    <pre>{{ctrl.test | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `this.test.ref().remove()`

Comment: ref is also undefined

Comment: Yeah, going through the code I was already wondering about that. You could definitely reconstruct the ref and call `remove()` on that, but it feels like there should be a simpler way. I'll see if I can dig something up. Kudos for using the `<pre>{{ctrl.test | json}}</pre>` approach to logging values btw, we're trying to promote that. :-)

Comment: yeah I've found a few workarounds like reconstructing the ref but just wondering what the best way to do this is. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 1):

Note that $bindTo() does not put the synchronized object on the scope, just the data. In this case, you have put the synchronized $firebaseObject at `this.test`, and then also bound the data to `this.test`.

Note that there is no reason, in this example, to utilize $bindTo(). You can call $remove() without creating a 3-way binding, which is only useful for making local changes to the object when you don't want to call $save() manually.

Also, the usage of $loaded is incorrect here. When you use $bindTo(), you'll want to use the promise it returns instead.

```
this.test.$bindTo($scope, 'ctrl.test')
  .then(function() {
    self.test.one = 1;
    self.test.two = 2;
    self.test.three = 3;
  });
```

Comment: so... how do I delete an angularfire object after calling $bindTo? Do I just need to create two $firebaseObjects and call $bindTo on one and $remove on the other? Is there any way to call $bindTo without it replacing the object you're calling it on?

Comment: Just tried something like this `this.test.$bindTo($scope, 'ctrl.test2');` and that seems to work. With this I can bind to `ctrl.test2` in the view and call `$remove` on `this.test` in the controller. It's not ideal but it's the best workaround I've found so far

Comment: I fail to see how that is a workaround. If you overwrite your $firebaseObject reference with a POJO, then it no longer exists and you can't call $remove. Not overwriting it is hardly a workaround here. And for the sake of being redundant, you don't need the $bindTo reference for anything you are doing here. You can directly use $firebaseObject references in your view.

Comment: This is a question about the behavior of `$bindTo` so it needs to use `$bindTo`. I could add an input box in the example but It wouldn't really make a different to my question. It is just a bit weird that when you use $bindTo you need to keep two references to the same data. One on the scope that can update the server and one that has the $firebaseObject methods like $remove.

Comment: $bindTo is a convenience for binding the data of a $firebaseObject to the scope. It's neither necessary nor itself a $firebaseObject. Trying to $watch on a synchronized, prototypical object would be a bit schizophrenic. If you want one object, bind the $firebaseObject to the scope. Call $save() when you make changes. And skip $bindTo.